# Are weights and trainable variables the same in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

That's all, I need to know if they are the same or correspond to different concepts.

When I use the `model.summary()` method, it gives me the amount of trainable variables, I need to know if they are the same as the weights

Comment: `model.summary()` returns you trainable and non-trainable parameters. Which variables are you referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Almost".

In most cases, yes, they are. But there are layers that use non-trainable weights for other purposes.

For instance, a `BatchNormalization` layers has four weight variables:

- mean: not trainable with backpropagation, but learnable from taking statistics from the data
- variance: not trainable with backpropagation, but learnable from taking statistics from  the data
- scale: trainable with backpropagation
- offset: trainable with backpropagation